# Does every real-closed field satisfy the first-order least upper bound axiom schema?

Tags: model-theory, ordered-fields

The theory of real-closed fields is usually axiomatized by the axioms of ordered fields, along with an axiom for existence of square roots of positive elements, and also an axiom schema stating that every odd degree polynomial has a root. I wonder, do these axioms imply the first-order least upper bound axiom schema? After all, every real-closed field is elementarily equivalent to the ordered field of real numbers, and certainly the real numbers satisfy the least upper bound axiom schema. If the answer is yes, can someone sketch a proof that the axioms of real-closed fields imply the first-order least upper bound axiom schema?

Comment: What is the first-order least upper bound axiom schema? Something like the supremum property for definable sets?

Comment: If the first-order LUB scheme is - as its name suggests - a set of first-order sentences, then obviously RCF implies it since RCF is complete.

Comment: "Every real-closed field is elementarily equivalent to the ordered field of real numbers, and certainly the real numbers satisfy the least upper bound axiom schema." You've sketched a proof yourself!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Well, the reason I asked this question is because I want to prove the least upper bound statement schema from the standard axioms of real-closed fields, namely the axioms of ordered fields plus the existence of square roots of positive elements plus the axioms of existence of roots of odd degree polynomials. I understand that real-closed fields can be characterized as those ordered fields which have the same first-order theory of real numbers, but I want to prove it directly from the axioms.